# Changing the position of a fixed image with scrollposition

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fixed

For my own portfolio I have an one-page website. To make it more personal i've created a low poly version of my head which is the fixed image. 
But how do i change its position depending on which section is currently being viewed? 
Example: When somebody is visiting the website and click on "About" the page would scroll down and the image would animate to the left so there will be more space for the content I want to display.

The CSS of the image:

```
img.imgPerson{
position: fixed;
z-index:2;
top: 48%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -242px;
margin-left: -175px;
}
```

What I've tried with Javascript already:

```
$(window).scrollTop() > 450 {
    $('.imgPerson').animate({
        "left": '350px'
        }, 300);
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: That function does not work unfortunately.

Comment: What function? `animate`? Check web console for errors.
`$(window).scrollTop() > 450 {` is incorrect, you need `if(...) { } `

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/260/)**.

You should use `if` keyword and you've to wrap your code by `scroll` event :

```
var animate_right = true;
var animate_left = true;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > 450 ){
    if(animate_right){
      animate_right=false;
      animate_left=true;

      $('.imgPerson').animate({"left": '550px'}, 300);
    }
  }else{
    if($('.imgPerson').css('left')=='550px'){
      animate_left=false;
      animate_right=true;

      $('.imgPerson').animate({"left": '250px'}, 300);
    }
  }
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var animate_right = true;
var animate_left = true;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > 450 ){
    if(animate_right){
      animate_right=false;
      animate_left=true;

      $('.imgPerson').animate({"left": '550px'}, 300);
    }
  }else{
    if($('.imgPerson').css('left')=='550px'){
      animate_left=false;
      animate_right=true;

      $('.imgPerson').animate({"left": '250px'}, 300);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}

img.imgPerson{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:2;
  top: 48%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -242px;
  margin-left: -175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='http://android-foundry.com/wp-content/uploads/signup2-img.png' class='imgPerson'/>
```

Comment: I've tried this but no result, is it possible for Bootstrap to interfere with it?
EDIT: The console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: It works, thanks! Is it possible when you scroll back, it will reposition to its previous position?